# 404 error in IIS 7.5 when redirecting in a frame

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 on my Windows 7 x64 system.  I have installed and properly configured IIS to allow me to run ASP.NET and Classic ASP.  For some reason though, when i do a redirect from an ASP.NET page to a classic asp page I get a 404 error.  I know the page is there.  If I copy and paste the URL of the classic ASP page into the address bar, it goes there fine.  Of course, the problem is that it expects to be in a frameset, so the pages go wonky on me.

Has anyone heard of this problem and/or know of a fix for it?  It worked fine in IIS 6 on my XP station.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I stepped through the code.  One thing i noticed.  The code is using the AntiXSS library from Microsoft and calling the URLEncode.  This is changing the ? and & codes.  If i change the code back to a plain redirect, it works fine.

Comment: Well, sounds like you found your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Does this frame have an address bar?  Are you sure the URL its attempting to load is really the one you're expecting?  Right-click and look at page properties.

Comment: The 404 error (i turned on show errors) has the url it is redirecting to on it.  I copy and paste the url from the error page and that will work.